# Laravel Mock Guzzle Http Client error during run php unit

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

I am developing a system using Laravel 7.28.4

In the system I have created a SMSService to be able to send SMS message, below is the SMSService code

https://codeshare.io/aYjDRM

below is the code which the unit test read for the testing

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Models\Booking;
use App\Traits\EmailTrait;
use App\Services\SMSService;

class BookingService extends BaseService
{
    use EmailTrait;
    
    public function update($input, $id)
    {
        $booking = Booking::find($id);

        try {
            $booking->update($input);

            $sms_service = new SMSService;

            $booking = Booking::whereId($id)->first();
            $booking->update(['status' => config('staticdata.booking_status.success')]);

            $this->sendBookingSuccessEmail($booking->applicantDetail->email, $booking->applicantDetail->first_name, $booking->reference_number);
            $sms_service->sendBookingSuccessSMS($booking->applicantDetail->mobile_no, $booking->reference_number);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            \Log::error($e);
            return $this->formatGeneralResponse(
                $e->getMessage(),
                config('staticdata.status_codes.error'),
                config('staticdata.http_codes.internal_server_error')
            );
        }

        return $this->formatGeneralResponse(
            config('staticdata.messages.update_success'),
            config('staticdata.status_codes.ok'),
            config('staticdata.http_codes.success')
        );
    }
    
  }
```

external sources : https://codeshare.io/aVLAeR

during running unit test i am using Mockery to replicate the service behaviour

below is the code that i run for the unit test

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Api;

use App\Models\ApplicantDetails;
use App\Models\Booking;
use App\Models\Branch;
use App\Models\Province;
use App\Models\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;

class BookingApiTest extends TestCase
{
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $user = factory(\App\Models\User::class)->create();
        Passport::actingAs(
            $user,
            ['frontend']
        );

        $response_data = [
            'status' => [
                'code' => '200',
                'description' => 'asd'
            ]
        ];

        $client = \Mockery::mock('overload:GuzzleHttp\Client');
        $client->shouldReceive('post')
            ->andReturn($client)
            ->shouldReceive('getStatusCode')
            ->andReturn(200)
            ->shouldReceive('getBody')
            ->andReturn($client)
            ->shouldReceive('getContents')
            ->andReturn(json_encode($response_data));
    }

    public function createARandomDateBetweenRange($start, $end, $filter = null)
    {
        $period = CarbonPeriod::between($start, $end);

        if ($filter) {
            $period = $period->filter($filter);
        }

        return $period;
    }

    public function testMakeBookingSuccess()
    {
        $isWeekday = function ($date) {
            return $date->isWeekday();
        };

        $period = $this->createARandomDateBetweenRange(Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'), '2021-12-31', $isWeekday);
        $period = $period->toArray();
        $book_date = $period[0]->format('Y-m-d');

        $data = [
            'sso_token' => '2345678976543456756543',
            'sso_id' => factory(ApplicantDetails::class)->create()->sso_id,
            'province' => factory(Province::class)->create()->id,
            'branch' => factory(Branch::class)->create()->id,
            'book_date' => $book_date,
            'meridiem' => 'am'
        ];

        $response = $this->post(route('api.ph-portal.booking.book'), $data);
        $response->assertJsonStructure(
            [
                'status_code',
                'message' => [
                    'encrypted_order_no',
                    'result',
                    'reference_number',
                    'booking_id'
                ]
            ]
        );
    }

    public function testMakeBookingFailedOnWeekend()
    {
        $isWeekend = function ($date) {
            return $date->isWeekend();
        };

        $period = $this->createARandomDateBetweenRange(Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'), '2021-12-31', $isWeekend);
        $period = $period->toArray();
        $book_date = $period[0]->format('Y-m-d');

        $data = [
            'sso_token' => '2345678976543456756543',
            'sso_id' => factory(ApplicantDetails::class)->create()->sso_id,
            'province' => factory(Province::class)->create()->id,
            'branch' => factory(Branch::class)->create()->id,
            'book_date' => $book_date,
            'meridiem' => 'am'
        ];

        $response = $this->post(route('api.ph-portal.booking.book'), $data);
        $response->assertExactJson(
            [
                'status_code' => config('staticdata.status_codes.validation_failed'),
                'errors' => [
                    'book_date' => ['date cannot be in weekend']
                ]
            ]
        );
    }

    public function testMakeBookingValidationFailed()
    {
        $data = [];

        $response = $this->post(route('api.ph-portal.booking.book'), $data);
        $response->assertExactJson(
            [
                'status_code' => config('staticdata.status_codes.validation_failed'),
                'detail' => config('staticdata.messages.validation_failed'),
                'field' => [
                    'branch' => 'The branch field is required.',
                    'meridiem' => 'The meridiem field is required.',
                    'province' => 'The province field is required.',
                    'book_date' => 'The book date field is required.',
                    'sso_id' => 'The sso id field is required.',
                ]
            ]
        );
    }

    public function testMakeBookingSlotFullFailed()
    {
        $isWeekday = function ($date) {
            return $date->isWeekday();
        };

        $period = $this->createARandomDateBetweenRange(Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'), '2021-12-31', $isWeekday);
        $period = $period->toArray();
        $book_date = $period[0]->format('Y-m-d');

        $branch_id = factory(Branch::class)->create(
            [
                'slot_am' => 3,
                'slot_pm' => 3,
            ]
        )->id;

        // am start
        factory(Booking::class, 3)->create(
            [
                'branch' => $branch_id,
                'book_date' => $book_date,
                'meridiem' => 'am',
            ]
        );

        $data = [
            'sso_token' => '2345678976543456756543',
            'sso_id' => factory(ApplicantDetails::class)->create()->sso_id,
            'province' => factory(Province::class)->create()->id,
            'branch' => $branch_id,
            'book_date' => $book_date,
            'meridiem' => 'am'
        ];

        $response = $this->post(route('api.ph-portal.booking.book'), $data);
        $response->assertExactJson(
            [
                'status_code' => config('staticdata.status_codes.validation_failed'),
                'errors' => [
                    'book_date' => ['Unable to book as the selected slot already full'],
                ]
            ]
        );

        // pm start
        factory(Booking::class, 3)->create(
            [
                'branch' => $branch_id,
                'book_date' => $book_date,
                'meridiem' => 'pm',
            ]
        );

        $data = [
            'sso_token' => '2345678976543456756543',
            'sso_id' => factory(ApplicantDetails::class)->create()->sso_id,
            'province' => factory(Province::class)->create()->id,
            'branch' => $branch_id,
            'book_date' => $book_date,
            'meridiem' => 'pm'
        ];

        $response = $this->post(route('api.ph-portal.booking.book'), $data);
        $response->assertExactJson(
            [
                'status_code' => config('staticdata.status_codes.validation_failed'),
                'errors' => [
                    'book_date' => ['Unable to book as the selected slot already full'],
                ]
            ]
        );
    }

    public function testListBookingPortalSuccess()
    {
        $branch = factory(Branch::class)->create();

        $data['sso_id'] = $branch->sso_id;

        $response = $this->post(route('api.ph-portal.booking.list'), $data);
        $response->assertJsonStructure(
            [
                'status_code',
                'data'
            ]
        );
    }

    public function testListBookingPortalNoDataFound()
    {
        factory(Branch::class)->create();

        $data['sso_id'] = "@s3randomStringxde2sx" . rand(1, 100);

        $response = $this->post(route('api.ph-portal.booking.list'), $data);
        $response->assertExactJson(
            [
                'status_code' => config('staticdata.status_codes.ok'),
                'data' => []
            ]
        );
    }

    public function testListBookingSuccess()
    {

        $response = $this->get(route('api.booking.list'));
        $response->assertJsonStructure(
            [
                'status_code',
                'data',
            ]
        );

        factory(Booking::class)->create()->toArray();

        $data = [
            'per_page' => "5"
        ];
        $response = $this->get(route('api.booking.list', $data));

        $response->assertJsonStructure(
            [
                'status_code',
                'data' => [
                    'current_page',
                    'data'
                ]
            ]
        );
    }

    public function testViewBookingDetailsSuccess()
    {
        $booking = factory(Booking::class)->create(['sso_id' => '534534534589p345-5934543058405345']);

        $response = $this->get(route('api.booking.details', $booking->id));
        $response->assertJsonStructure(
            [
                'status_code',
                'data' => [
                    'id',
                    'sso_id',
                    'user_id',
                    'province',
                    'branch',
                    'book_date',
                    'created_at',
                    'updated_at',
                    'meridiem',
                    'status',
                    'reference_number',
                    'applicant_detail',
                    'province_data',
                    'branch_data',
                    'transaction'
                ]
            ]
        );
    }

    public function testViewBookingDetailsNoDataFound()
    {

        $response = $this->get(route('api.booking.details', 99999999999999999));
        $response->assertExactJson(
            [
                'status_code' => config('staticdata.status_codes.ok'),
                'data' => null
            ]
        );
    }

    public function testViewBookingDetailsPortalSuccess()
    {
        $booking = factory(Booking::class)->create();

        $response = $this->get(
            route(
                'api.ph-portal.booking.details',
                [
                    'sso_id' => $booking->sso_id,
                    'id' => $booking->id
                ]
            )
        );

        $response->assertJsonStructure(
            [
                'status_code',
                'data' => [
                    'id',
                    'sso_id',
                    'user_id',
                    'book_date',
                    'meridiem',
                    'status',
                    'reference_number',
                    'applicant_detail',
                ]
            ]
        );
    }

    public function testViewBookingDetailsPortalValidationFailed()
    {
        $booking = factory(Booking::class)->create();

        $response = $this->get(
            route(
                'api.ph-portal.booking.details',
                [
                    'sso_id' => 999999999999999,
                    'id' => $booking->id
                ]
            )
        );

        $response->assertExactJson(
            [
                'status_code' => config('staticdata.status_codes.validation_failed'),
                'detail' => config('staticdata.messages.validation_failed'),
                'field' => [
                    'sso_id' => 'The selected sso id is invalid.'
                ]
            ]
        );
    }

    public function testBookingUpdateSuccess()
    {
        $booking = factory(Booking::class)->create();

        $response_data = [
            'umid' => 1,
            'clientMessageId' => null,
            'destination' => '+61212323',
            'encoding' => 'GSM7',
            'status' => [
                'code' => '200',
                'description' => 'asd'
            ]
        ];

        $client = \Mockery::mock('overload:GuzzleHttp\Client');
        $client->shouldReceive('post')
            ->andReturn($client)
            ->shouldReceive('getStatusCode')
            ->andReturn(200)
            ->shouldReceive('getBody')
            ->andReturn($client)
            ->shouldReceive('getContents')
            ->andReturn(json_encode($response_data));

        $data = [
            'branch' => factory(Branch::class)->create()->id,
            'book_date' => '2020-12-01',
            'meridiem' => 'am',
        ];

        $response = $this->post(route('api.booking.update', $booking->id), $data);
        $response->assertExactJson(
            [
                'status_code' => config('staticdata.status_codes.ok'),
                'message' => config('staticdata.messages.update_success')
            ]
        );
    }

    public function testBookingUpdateValidationFailed()
    {
        $response = $this->post(route('api.booking.update', 9999999));
        $response->assertExactJson(
            [
                'status_code' => config('staticdata.status_codes.validation_failed'),
                'detail' => config('staticdata.messages.validation_failed'),
                'field' => [
                    'id' => 'The selected id is invalid.',
                    'branch' => 'The branch field is required.'
                ]
            ]
        );

        $booking = factory(Booking::class)->create();

        $data = [
            'branch' => factory(Branch::class)->create()->id,
            'book_date' => '2020-12-01',
        ];

        $response = $this->post(route('api.booking.update', $booking->id), $data);
        $response->assertExactJson(
            [
                'status_code' => config('staticdata.status_codes.validation_failed'),
                'detail' => config('staticdata.messages.validation_failed'),
                'field' => [
                    'meridiem' => 'The meridiem field is required when book date is present.'
                ]
            ]
        );
    }

    public function testRequestNewBookingDateSuccess()
    {
        $booking = factory(Booking::class)->create();

        $response = $this->post(route('api.ph-portal.booking.request_new_bookdate', $booking->id), $data);
        $response->assertExactJson(
            [
                'status_code' => config('staticdata.status_codes.ok'),
                'message' => config('staticdata.messages.process_success')
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

external sources : https://codeshare.io/Gk6eDA

the unit test are able to run using this command

`php artisan test --filter BookingApiTest`

but error below appear during the unit test and i am unable to track on why this happen.

```
✕ booking update success

  Tests:  1 failed, 11 passed, 5 pending

   ErrorException

  Undefined index: umid

  at C:\laragon\www\nbi-backend\app\Services\SMSService.php:13
     9| {
    10|     public function saveSMSData($data)
    11|     {
    12|         $data = [
  > 13|             'umid' => $data['umid'],
    14|             'client_message_id' => $data['clientMessageId'],
    15|             'destination' => $data['destination'],
    16|             'encoding' => $data['encoding'],
    17|             'code' => $data['status']['code'],

  1   C:\laragon\www\nbi-backend\app\Services\SMSService.php:13
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Undefined index: umid", "C:\laragon\www\nbi-backend\app\Services\SMSService.php", [])

  2   C:\laragon\www\nbi-backend\app\Services\SMSService.php:50
      App\Services\SMSService::saveSMSData([])
```

i have tried using

`php artisan tinker`

then write the command as below

`$sms = new SMSService`

`$sms->sendBookingSuccessSMS('601123456767','TEST123');`

but the result came out as

`null`

kindly help on how to fix this issue or how to trace of how the problem occur

Thank you.

Some additional code info

> 

config staticdata file

https://codeshare.io/5N8lgm

.env file

https://codeshare.io/aVLAB4

composer.json file

https://codeshare.io/G84Eev

> 

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me. You don't have a `umid` index. Where is the code that call `saveSMSData` function?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte https://codeshare.io/aVLAeR the code calls $sms->sendBookingSuccessSMS($arg1,$arg2) which then call the saveSMSData function

Comment: Can't find `saveSMSData` in this code.

Comment: this code from here
https://codeshare.io/aVLAeR

contains
$sms_service->sendBookingSuccessSMS($booking->applicantDetail->mobile_no, $booking->reference_number);

in which it calls the function at here

https://codeshare.io/aYjDRM

at line 50 theres the 
$this->saveSMSData($response_data);
code

Comment: Update your question with all relevant code. Don't use external source as it's terrible to find the information.

Comment: done update question with all relevent code details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224852/discussion-between-farhanz95-and-felippe-duarte).

Comment: the problem have been fixed, instead of mocking on the Guzzle Http Client itself, ill just mock on the SMS Service like this https://codeshare.io/2KeVAM